# How to prevent input field inside form from submitting when enter key is pressed?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple form.

Input fields, checkboxes, radio buttons and finally SUBMIT button.

I use jQuery to perform AJAX validation, however when a user presses ENTER inside the input field it submits the form!

How do I stop this from happening on this form (not all input fields)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

suppose your inputs for which you don't want to submit on enter has class `noSubmit` then use this code:

```
$(function(){
     $("input.noSubmit").keypress(function(e){
         var k=e.keyCode || e.which;
         if(k==13){
             e.preventDefault();
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onsubmit` handler to trap form submission and perform validation:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
  // return true to submit form or false to stop
}
</script>
```